# how to manage kafka broker by systemd?

Tags: apache-kafka, systemd

I am trying to manager kafka broker by systemd. here is a unit-file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Kafka with broker id (%i)
After=network.target
After=zk.service

[Service]
Type=simple

SyslogIdentifier=kafka (%i)
WorkingDirectory=/opt/service/kafka_2.11-0.9.0.1
LimitNOFILE=16384:163840

ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c 'bin/kafka-server-start.sh /opt/service/units/kafka/%i.properties'
ExecStop=/usr/bin/bash -c 'bin/kafka-server-stop.sh /opt/service/units/kafka/%i.properties'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

with that file, I can start kafka by command `systemctl --user start kafka@0.service` and `systemctl --user start kafka@1.service`.

But when I try to kill those daemons by `systemctl --user stop kafka@0.service`, all two daemons are stoped! so, why could not I kill just only one broker?

Comment: See also https://gist.github.com/kwilczynski/6c6645dfdc8de4cd9ed1 (untested)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Kafka with broker id (%i)
After=network.target
After=zk.service

[Service]
Type=forking

SyslogIdentifier=kafka (%i)
Restart=on-failure
LimitNOFILE=16384:163840

ExecStart=/opt/service/kafka_2.11-0.9.0.1/bin/kafka-server-start.sh -daemon /opt/service/units/kafka/%i.properties

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```