# Start Apache Kafka in Kraft mode as a servcice on Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, apache-kafka, service

I am using the instructions from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39901893/919480) to set-up Kafka as a service on Ubuntu-22.04 on AWS EC2. I am installing Kafka using instructions [from here](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart). Here is my `/etc/init.d/kafka` file. Please note that, I am able to launch Kafka successfully from the command line; but, the launch fails as a service.

```bash
KAFKA_HOME=/opt/kafka
# See how we were called.
case "$1" in
  start)
        # Start daemon.
        echo "Generate cluster UUID"
        KAFKA_CLUSTER_ID="$(${KAFKA_HOME}/bin/kafka-storage.sh random-uuid)"
        echo "Format log directories"
        ${KAFKA_HOME}/bin/kafka-storage.sh format -t $KAFKA_CLUSTER_ID -c ${KAFKA_HOME}/config/kraft/server.properties
        echo "Start Kafka server"
        ${KAFKA_HOME}/bin/kafka-server-start.sh -daemon ${KAFKA_HOME}/config/kraft/server.properties
        ;;
  stop)
        # Stop daemons.
        echo "Shutting down Kafka";
        pid=`ps ax | grep -i 'kafka.Kafka' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}'`
        if [ -n "$pid" ]
          then
          kill -9 $pid
        else
          echo "Kafka was not Running"
        fi
        ;;
  restart)
        $0 stop
        sleep 2
        $0 start
        ;;
  status)
        pid=`ps ax | grep -i 'kafka.Kafka' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}'`
        if [ -n "$pid" ]
          then
          echo "Kafka is Running as PID: $pid"
        else
          echo "Kafka is not Running"
        fi
        ;;
  *)
        echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|status}"
        exit 1
esac

exit 0
```

Upon running `sudo systemctl kafka start` I get the following error.

```bash
Job for kafka.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status kafka.service" and "journalctl -xeu kafka.service" for details.
```

And, `sudo systemctl kafka status` shows this.

```bash
× kafka.service
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/kafka; generated)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2023-10-27 15:42:14 UTC; 2s ago
       Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Process: 8492 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/kafka start (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
        CPU: 946us

Oct 27 15:42:14 ip-172-31-15-126 systemd[8492]: kafka.service: Failed to execute /etc/init.d/kafka: Exec format error
Oct 27 15:42:14 ip-172-31-15-126 systemd[8492]: kafka.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /etc/init.d/kafka: Exec format error
Oct 27 15:42:14 ip-172-31-15-126 systemd[1]: Starting kafka.service...
Oct 27 15:42:14 ip-172-31-15-126 systemd[1]: kafka.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Oct 27 15:42:14 ip-172-31-15-126 systemd[1]: kafka.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 27 15:42:14 ip-172-31-15-126 systemd[1]: Failed to start kafka.service.
```

Here is my Java version - if it helps.

```bash
java -version
openjdk version "19.0.2" 2023-01-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 19.0.2+7-Ubuntu-0ubuntu322.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0.2+7-Ubuntu-0ubuntu322.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Please let me know how to launch Kafka as a service.

Comment: have you tried to run the script manually ? ```/etc/init.d/kafka start``` what is the output ? and can you put ```#!/bin/bash``` to the top of /etc/init.d/kafka and retry ?

Comment: `sudo /etc/init.d/kafka start` did launch Kafka successfully.

Comment: than putting the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) on top probably will fix this error. if it does not fix the error you can check journalctl as explained [here](https://serverfault.com/a/826685) also this maybe related to systemd configuration in that case I would suggest to create a service file something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37891610/175554)

Comment: Yes, that worked! Can you please explain why adding `#!/bin/bash` at the top worked?

Comment: Also, please write your comment as an answer so that I can acknowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) on top of the starting shell script probably will fix this error. If it does not fix the error you can check [journalctl](https://serverfault.com/a/826685) as explained here also this maybe related to systemd configuration in that case I would suggest to create a service file something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37891610/175554)

[why we use shebang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3009280/175554), in short it is to telling linux system to use bash to run the code "below" in the file.

working code below

```bash
#!/bin/bash
KAFKA_HOME=/opt/kafka
# See how we were called.
case "$1" in
  start)
        # Start daemon.
        echo "Generate cluster UUID"
        KAFKA_CLUSTER_ID="$(${KAFKA_HOME}/bin/kafka-storage.sh random-uuid)"
        echo "Format log directories"
        ${KAFKA_HOME}/bin/kafka-storage.sh format -t $KAFKA_CLUSTER_ID -c ${KAFKA_HOME}/config/kraft/server.properties
        echo "Start Kafka server"
        ${KAFKA_HOME}/bin/kafka-server-start.sh -daemon ${KAFKA_HOME}/config/kraft/server.properties
        ;;
  stop)
        # Stop daemons.
        echo "Shutting down Kafka";
        pid=`ps ax | grep -i 'kafka.Kafka' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}'`
        if [ -n "$pid" ]
          then
          kill -9 $pid
        else
          echo "Kafka was not Running"
        fi
        ;;
  restart)
        $0 stop
        sleep 2
        $0 start
        ;;
  status)
        pid=`ps ax | grep -i 'kafka.Kafka' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}'`
        if [ -n "$pid" ]
          then
          echo "Kafka is Running as PID: $pid"
        else
          echo "Kafka is not Running"
        fi
        ;;
  *)
        echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|status}"
        exit 1
esac

exit 0
```